# Scikit Model accuracy significantly differing after joblib dump and reload

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the dataset. I'm using but I'm using a standard pipeline with an mlp model to train and produce a joblib file for production. Unfortunately, whenever I attempt to reload the notebook and use the loaded model it works vastly differently than it should.

```
data = pd.read_csv('CleanData.csv')
data =  data.drop(columns=['loudness'])
full_prep_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('Scaler',StandardScaler()),
    ('MLPModel',MLPClassifier(max_iter=400))
])
column_split = (set(data.columns))
column_split.remove('genre')
data = data.drop_duplicates(subset=list(column_split))
Xval = data[column_split]
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
Yval = encoder.fit_transform(data['genre'])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (Xval, Yval, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 29,stratify=Yval)
full_prep_pipeline.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred = full_prep_pipeline.predict(x_test)
metric= metrics.classification_report (y_pred,y_test)
print (metric)
dump(encoder,'Encoder.joblib')
dump(full_prep_pipeline,'MLPModelPipeline.joblib')
```

. When I first ran this I received an accuracy of roughly 50%. When I then attempted to load the model again on a different file.

```
data = pd.read_csv('CleanData.csv')
data =  data.drop(columns=['loudness'])
pipeline = load('MLPModelPipeline.joblib')
encoder =  load('Encoder.joblib')
column_split = (set(data.columns))
column_split.remove('genre')
data = data.drop_duplicates(subset=list(column_split))
Xval = data[column_split]
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
Yval = encoder.fit_transform(data['genre'])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (Xval, Yval, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 29,stratify=Yval)
y_pred = pipeline.predict(x_test)
metric= metrics.classification_report (y_pred,y_test)
print (metric)
```

. I received an accuracy of less than 5% as it simply predicted the same value over and over again. I made sure to put it all in a pipeline in case it was a scaling dilemma, but that didn't seem to be the issue. Curious about other people's thoughts on the matter. I also tried this with a QDA Model and a Logistic Regression Model but the same issue showed up.
I'm decently sure this isn't a problem of overfitting as I was able to get similar levels of accuracy(~50%) with cross-validation sets.

Edit: I tried to see if this problem was reproducible with different datasets, and after testing with the classic digits dataset I could **not** reproduce the problem with that dataset. Not sure if this is because of the simplicity of that dataset or if it's an actual problem with the method I used now.
Edit: The dataset is decently well proportioned here is the outpout of y_train.value_counts().

```
3     9379
5     7743
22    7358
0     7257
1     7141
8     7129
2     7122
4     7059
18    6967
23    6874
11    6770
20    6739
17    6598
13    6543
6     6283
12    6109
21    5365
9     5349
7     4918
19    4381
15    4314
10    3962
14    3748
16    3530
dtype: int64
```

Edit: Apparently this isn't simply a scaling issue(with worse numbers) as I tried the process without the scaler and it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I put the output of value_counts for you to see. The F1 score, precision and recall are roughly equal to the accuracy.

Comment: Check that the column order in your data is the same each time; subsetting dataframe by _sets_ of column names might be an issue.